# ASP.NET MVC Display Template for Generic Type

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I am trying to use the model ListModel as a generic list model. I would like to enter on the page

```
@Html.DisplayForModel()
```

However the MVC is not correctly finding the templated file "ListModel.cshtml". It must work differently for generic models. What should I name the templated file in order for it to correctly be located?

```
public class ListModel<T>
{
public IEnumerable<T> Models { get; set; }
public string NextPage { get; set; }
}
```

I would expect it to look for `Shared/DisplayTemplates/ListModel.ascx` but it doesn't. Does anyone know?

**Edit:**

I did end up solving this by simply removing the generic parameter like so. I do want to know if you can still have a generic file name though.

```
public class ListModel
{
    public IEnumerable Models {get;set;}
    public string NextPage {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: I don't understand anything of what you're trying to do, could you explain again ?

Comment: could DisplayForModel overload that takes template name help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround, could you decorate the `ListModel<T>` class with the `UIHint` attribute to force it to use the template you want?

For example,

```
[UIHint("ListModel")]
public class ListModel<T>
{
...
```

Comment: The UIHint attribute cannot be applied to classes like this, only properties and fields.

Comment: @Darren, that's a damn shame :) This would have been perfect

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible.

Think about it: If you somehow was able to declare the template as generic (say by calling it ListModel`1.ascx or something) how would the MVC runtime handle any specific instances of the model? And how would you display the generic properties/fields in the template?

I haven't been able to find a place where MS specifically states that generic models are disallowed, but I can't see how they would make it work.

This is also supported by the observation that if you try to create a strongly-typed view, then generic classes are filtered out of the drop-down box.

Comment: It would be able t decide what to do with the properties through contravariance and the dynamic type.

Comment: It could use other DisplayTemplate/EditorTemplate for instances of the generic type just as you could render any type using `Object.cshtml` template. It'll be really useful if you're able to provide templates for rendering a collection of items e.g. TableListView IconsView MasterDetailsView etc. etc. But I still agree that this isn't possible currently. However it is a totally implementable solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly specify your Template, then MVC will find it as usual.

```
@Html.DisplayForModel("ListModel")
```

and similarly

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.AProperty,"TemplateName")
```